# JQuery - changing an audio song on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I read the HTML5 Audio reference on W3Schools and tried to figure out how to change songs. Their example shows changing a video. I want to do this using jquery when I click on a particular song.

The song I click on has the id `#song-two`

```
$("#song-two").click(function() {
  $("#mp3_src").src("songs/songtwo.mp3");
});
```

but the song does not get loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: Is $("#song-two") an <audio> tag?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#song-two").click(function() {
  $("#mp3_src").attr("src", "http://example.com/new_url.mp4"​​​​)​
});
```

instead of

```
$("#song-two").click(function() {
  $("#mp3_src").src("songs/songtwo.mp3);
});
```

Comment: That is what I have in my own production site using jQuery 1.6.4 and it works in all browsers without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
$("#audiochange").attr("src","songs/songtwo.mp3");
```

---

You can also try to provide the full url, i.e.:

```
$("#audiochange").attr("src","http://yoursite.com/songs/songtwo.mp3");
```

---

References:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/